# Rotate a fontImage in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

```
Image shareIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_REPLY, s);
shareIcon = shareIcon.rotate(180);
ShareButton shareButton = new ShareButton();
shareButton.setIcon(shareIcon);
```

How can I flip the image here? The rotate method does nothing.

The answer below by shai doesn't work in my project

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.components.ShareButton;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Rotate");
        hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Image shareIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_REPLY, new Button("").getUnselectedStyle(), 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 45) {
            ShareButton s = new ShareButton();
            s.setIcon(shareIcon.rotate(i));
            hi.add(s);
        }
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if (current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog) current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

If you want to see the project, heres the project:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ATnICIY2S8OEtUU2lPSlFid3M

Comment: hareButton is meant to be ShareButton, right? If you rotate 90 degrees, what do you experience?

Comment: I want to flip the icon of share button.

Comment: Have you tried to rotate it by 90 degrees?

Comment: yeah with 45,90,180, nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Image shareIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_REPLY, new Button("").getUnselectedStyle(), 5);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 360 ; i += 45) {
    ShareButton s = new ShareButton();
    s.setIcon(shareIcon.rotate(i));
    hi.add(s);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in my project. I have kept the project link above in the question as well.

Comment: Is it possible your libraries are very old? Try doing an update client libs to the latest and make sure you aren't using versioned build.

Comment: I don't think so. I have updated the cn1 plugin just a few weeks ago and updating the project library from "update project libs" under "general properties" does not solve the problem. Refresh cn1lib files is also done. Is there a way to know if my libs are old or new?

Comment: In the `codenameone_settings.properties` the `libVersion` value should be `140` as of this writing

Comment: OK, I see the problem. There seems to be a bug in the scale mode of the simulator which doesn't apply in the 3gs skin I used. Uncheck scrollable in the simulator and it should work. I've filed an issue on this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1971 Thanks!